# AJAX Request with ClojureScript sometimes has nil as parameter on Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, clojure, clojurescript

### Edit

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4W2q/) with a minimal example. The problem is that in Firefox it does not matter where I click on the button. The target of the Event is always the button.

In Chrome on the other hand if I click on the span the target of the event is the span not the button.

Is this the expected behaviour?

### Original

I wrote a litte webapp in clojure using clojurescript on the client side which contains the
following route:

```
(POST "/admin/delete-user" {p :params}
        (println (str "Deleted User: "(pr-str (:username p))))
        (db/delete-user (:username p))
        "Expected return value")
```

One page contains the following button:

```
<button class="delete btn" data-delete="USERNAME">...</button>
```

This button is used in conjunction with the following ClojureScript:

```
(listen!
   (by-class "delete")
   :click (fn [evt]
            (let [target (evt/target evt)
                  username (:data-delete (attrs target))]
              (POST "/admin/delete-user"
                    {:format :edn
                     :params {:username username}
                     :handler (fn [resp]
                                (log "User deleted")
                                (load-user-table))
                     :error-handler (fn [resp] (log "Error during user deletion"))})
              (log "User " username))))
```

I use `domina` for dom manipulation and event handling and `cljs-ajax` for my ajax requests. The
code is compiled using `advanced` optimizations in my settings for `lein cljsbuild`.

On firefox this code works fine but when I use my code in Chrome I
"sometimes" get the behaviour that instead of the username in the
`data-delete` attribute of the button `nil` is used as a parameter.

When this behaviour occurs I can click on the button repeatedly and nothing
happens. Then after a couple of many clicks it works.

I also checked the cosole output and no errors occur and it jus
t shows
nothing after logging "User " therefore `username` must be `null`.

How can `username` be null in Chrome?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the event target is always the `<button>` element itself, and not possibly some sub-element (an icon, or a `<span>` or whatever)?

Comment: I thought so but I tested it anyway. The span element in the button with the icon seemed to receive the event "sometimes". I will write a litte addendum to my question because I am still confused ...

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

Instead of `(target evt)` I have to use the `current-target`. In Firefox the click event is triggered on the `button` in Chrome on the `span`.